# javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: HTTP 404 Not Found

Tags: java, rest, get, jersey

Below is the web.xml config file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" 
version="3.1">
 <display-name>pgwrapper</display-name>
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-
 class>
<init-param>
  <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
  <param-value>com.example.postgres.wrapper</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Below is my ServiceClassProvider.java file:

```
 @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
 @Path("/pg")
 public class PostgresDBServiceProvider {
      static final String HOST = "select * from host";

     /**
        * @return All Host Ids
        * @throws Exception
     */
     @GET
     @Path("/getAllHostIds")
     @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
     public static String getAllHostIds() throws Exception {
         List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
         String hostId = null;;
         ListWrapper listWrapper = new ListWrapper();
         Statement st = PostgresDBConnector.getInstance().createStatement();
         ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(HOST);
         while (rs.next()) {
             hostId = rs.getString("host_id");
             break;
      }
       return hostId;
     }
```

Client.java:

```
   public class PostgresClient {

   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
   .......................
   Client client =
        ClientBuilder.newBuilder().withConfig(config)
              .hostnameVerifier(new InsecureHostnameVerifier())
              .sslContext(ctx).build();

  WebTarget target = client.target(getBaseURI());
  String hostIp =
        target.path("rest")
              .path("getAllHostIds").request()
              .accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).get(String.class);

  System.out.println("hostIp:" + hostIp);

 }

      private static URI getBaseURI() {
     return UriBuilder.fromUri("https://192.168.100.108:8443/pg").build();
  }

 }
```

While running thje client ,I am getting below error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: HTTP 404 Not 
 Found
```

at

```
 org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.convertToException(JerseyInvocation.java:1020)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.translate(JerseyInvocation.java:819)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.access$700(JerseyInvocation.java:92)
```

My Tomcat server is running on 8443,but I am unable to execute this rest endpoint, not sure which configuration is missed here.Need pointers to proceed in this.

Comment: Try executing this `https://192.168.100.108:8443/<<you_web_context_name>>/rest/pg/getAllHostIds` from your web browser and see what happens?

Comment: is this <display-name>isvmwrapper</display-name>(isvmwrapper) is web_context_name here?sorry m beginner to these things,so unsure...

Comment: No, not that one. It would really depend on how you are deploying your application, if you don't know then please give me url for your index.jsp or index.html access.

Comment: cant find index.jsp,i am using reference from  http://howtodoinjava.com/jersey/jersey-restful-client-examples/  for connection to postgres sql and do GET operation on a table

Comment: See in your link you hv - `http://localhost:8080/JerseyDemos/rest`, there `JerseyDemos` is the web context, thts the name of your deployment, if you are deploying from a WAR then name of the WAR will be your web context, if you are deploying like a hot deployment then "WebContent" will be your web context.

Comment: https://192.168.100.108:8443/pgwrapper/rest/pg/getAllHostIds,even after giving war file name,getting same 404 error

Comment: What is your admin console url?